# Apache Spark: Regex with ReduceByKey is lot slower than GREP command

Tags: regex, performance, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a file with strings (textData) and a set of regex filters (regx) that I want to apply and get count. Before we migrated to Spark, I used GREP as follows:

```
from subprocess import check_output
result={}
for reg in regx: # regx is a list of all the filters
   result[reg] = system.exec('grep -e ' + reg + 'file.txt | wc -l')
```

Note: I am paraphrasing here with 'system.exec', I am actually using check_output.

I upgraded to SPARK for other things, so I want to also take the benefit of spark here. So I wrote up this code.

```
import re

sc = SparkContext('local[*]')
rdd = sc.textFile('file.txt') #containing the strings as before
result = rdd.flatMap(lambda line: [(reg, line) for reg in regx])
            .map(lambda line: (line[0], len(re.findall(line[0], line[1]))))
            .reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
            .collect()
```

I thought I was being smart but the code is actually slower. Can anyone point out any obvious errors? I am running it as 
    spark-submit --master local[*] filename.py

I haven't run both versions on the same exact data to check exactly how much slower. I could easily do that, if required. When I checked localhost:4040 most of the time is being taken by the reduceByKey job.

To give a sense of time taken, the number of rows in the file are 100,000 with average #chars per line of ~1000 or so. The number of filters len(regx)=20. This code has been running for 44min on an 8core processor with 128GB RAM.

EDIT: just to add, the number of regex filters and textfiles will multiply 100 folds in the final system. Plus rather than writing/reading data from text files, I would be querying for the data in rdd with an SQL statement. Hence, I thought Spark was a good choice.

Comment: This would be an interesting question if you observed that `grep` is much slower than Spark. The other way around, especially in the local mode, it is not even remotely surprising. While your code could be improved in a quite a few way expecting similar performance, in non distributed setup, as `grep` is unrealistic.

Comment: Have you tried to (increase) change the `minPartitions` parameter in `textFile`?

Comment: @zero323 well, I am currently on a dev env but would be moving to a distributed setup. Would be really helpful if you can elaborate on the 'improved in quite a few ways'. I would appreciate that very much.

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani thx. I did, and it didnt help at all. Perhaps since it isnt distributed as suggested by zero. Any other thoughts?

Comment: What is the average size of the line? Are the lines unique? If not what is the expected number of unique lines?

Comment: @zero323: as mentioned there are about 1000 char per line, they need not strictly be unique, but that would be a very rare case.

Comment: just to add, the number of regex filters and textfiles will multiply 100 folds in the final system. Plus rather than writing/reading data from text files, I would be querying for the data in rdd with an SQL statement. Hence, I thought Spark was a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a quite heavy user of sort as well, and whilst Spark doesn't feel as fast in a local setup, you should consider some other things:

- How big is your dataset? sort swaps records to /tmp when requiring high ammounts of RAM.
- How many RAM have you assigned to your Spark app? by default it has only 1GB, that's pretty unfair in sorting vs a sort command without RAM restrictions.
- Are both tasks executed on the same machine? is the Spark machine a virtual appliance running in an "auto-expand" disk file? (bad performance).
- Spark Clusters will spread your tasks across multiple servers automatically. If running on Hadoop, remember that files are sliced in 128MB blocks, each block can be an RDD partition.

I.e. in a Hadoop cluster, RDD partitions could be processed in parallel. This is where you'll nottice performance.

Spark will deal with Hadoop to do its best to achieve "data locality", meaning that your processes run directly against local hard drives, otherwise the data is going to be replicated across the network, as when executing *reduce-alike* processes. These are the *stages*. Understanding stages and how data is moved across the executors will lead you nice improvements, moreover considering that **sort is of type "reduce" and it triggers a new execution stage on Spark, potentially moving data across the network.** Having spare resources on the same nodes where maps are being executed can save a lot of network overhead.

Otherwise it will still work frankly well, and you can't destroy a file in HDFS by mistake :-)

This is where you really get performance and safety of data and execution, by spreading the task in parallel to work against a lot of hard drives in a self-recovering execution environment.

In a local setup you simply feel it irresponsive, mostly because it takes a bit to load, launch and track back the process, but it feels quick and safe when dealing with many GBs across several nodes.

I do also love shell scripting and I deal with reasonable ammounts of GBs quite often, but you can't regex-match 5 TB of data without distributing disk IO or paying for RAM as if there was no tomorrow.